# How do I confirm that the person sending an action is the same as a user in the parameter?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, accounts, action, contract-development

Specific example from a contract:

```
...
void hi(name user){
  // verification here, require_auth(user)?
  print(user);
}
...
```

I've tried `require_auth(user)` but that seems to always fail unless the user itself is the contract's creator.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us how you call the action? What kind of response do you get?

Answer (score 2):

`require_auth(user)` will ensure the sender of the transaction has the correct permission, which is what you're intending. Perhaps the way you're calling the action is incorrect?

When using `cleos push action ...` the `-p` (or `--permission`) option allows you to specify the account authority you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

OP here, lost the account I made this post with. I figured it out!
Log:

```
$ cleos push action CONTRACT_NAME hi '[useruseruser]' -p CONTRACT_NAME
Error 3090004: Missing required authority
Ensure that you have the related authority inside your transaction!;
If you are currently using 'cleos push action' command, try to add the relevant authority using -p option.
Error Details:
missing authority of useruseruser
pending console output:
```

By doing `cleos push action CONTRACT_NAME hi '[useruseruser]' -p useruseruser` instead, it returns `Hello, useruseruser`. Since I have authority over the useruseruser account the action worked.

Thanks for the advice on where to look!

Comment: Glad you got there, I updated my answer to make it more clear as well :)